# Multilingual sentence generation with Hugging Face

Tags: huggingface, text-generation, llm, t5

For an application I need to generate some random sentences, i.e. I don't need the output sentences to have any specific link to the prompt other than using the same language. If possible I need this process to be multilingual, i.e. to accept and generate in as many languages as possible. I also need to be able to run this process as many times as I want, this is why a dataset isn't suitable (fixed size).

I tried using [mT5](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/mt5) which seems to be the most suitable model for my requirements, right? but I can't get anything out of it. Is it because it needs to be fine-tuned, as I read in different places? If so, any advice how I do this in my case?

Ideally I would also need this not to require too much computation, even at the cost of grammaticality/meaning of sentences.

Comment: Besides the fact that the generated sentence must match the prompt's language, are there other requirements? Does it need to be a specific length? Otherwise, datasets like tatoeba (https://huggingface.co/datasets/tatoeba) or Wikipedia (https://huggingface.co/datasets/wikimedia/wikipedia) might be large enough and cover enough languages for your use case

Comment: @ValentinCalomme thanks for the advice, I might use this. Actually the full application requires generating sentences until a condition is satisfied, this is why I'd prefer generating from a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options there:

- Different models on HuggingFace

[GPT2](https://huggingface.co/gpt2) should fit your use case. If performance is really critical, I'd give [distilGPT2](https://huggingface.co/distilgpt2) a try. They only generate English sentences but you should be able to translate things well using something like [T5](https://huggingface.co/t5-small).

- "Manual" generation

NLTK provides a way to generate sentences using context-free grammar. It might be more time consuming, and might not yield sentences that make sense, but you would definitely do great on performance.

```py
from nltk import CFG
from nltk.parse.generate import generate

grammar = CFG.fromstring(
    """
  S -> NP VP
  VP -> V NP | V NP PP
  PP -> P NP
  V -> "saw" | "ate" | "walked"
  NP -> "John" | "Mary" | "Bob" | Det N | Det N PP
  Det -> "a" | "an" | "the" | "my"
  N -> "man" | "dog" | "cat" | "telescope" | "park"
  P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
"""
)

# Generating sentences
for sentence in generate(grammar, n=5):
    print(" ".join(sentence))
```

- Build your own model

Back in 2015, I saw this article: https://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ from Andrej Karpathy. I played around with it and realized that it was relatively easy to generate reasonable text using only a very small RNN. You'd need training data, but your model would be much smaller than a GPT2 or an mT5